# Resizing custom UITableViewCell's subviews on creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm attempting to create a custom UITableViewCell with its own XIB, of which contains two important, editable components:

- UILabel
- UIImage with 'end-cap insets' - this image sits behind the label, and resizes with it

When I create my UITableViewCell I can set its label's text easily, but in the same method I also try to change the UIImage's frame to match that of the UILabel's. However, this is not happening until I 'reload' the cell by scrolling the table view to dequeue it and bring it back into view.

I create the custom table view cell in my view controller's .m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *UITableViewCellIdentifier = @"msgCell";

    RMMessageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:UITableViewCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MessageCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell customInit]; //This sets up the ImageView's image etc
    }

    [cell setMessageValue:[_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //SEE BELOW

    return cell;
}
```

...And in my custom cell's .m, I deal with setting the text label and resizing the image with this method:

```
- (void)setMessageValue:(NSString *)message {

    _testLabel.text = message;
    // Assume the text label's frame has already been set to the message's length 
    // (will add this in once I figure out how to change the imageView's 
    // frame correctly)

    // Set the image view's frame to the label's
    // THIS DOES NOT TAKE EFFECT UNTIL THE TABLE VIEW IS RE-SCROLLED
    CGRect frame = _imageView.frame;
    frame.size.width = _testLabel.frame.size.width + 8;
    _imageView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: What auto resizing rules do you have set on the label and the image view? What row height are you setting? You shouldn't be setting the frame of cell content directly like this. It also isn't a great idea to be the owner of the table cell (subclass the table cell to reference the sun views instead).

Comment: They resize to fit the cell's height, but this isn't a question of height; what I'm trying to do is stretch the image horizontally behind the UILabel - so, for example, if one cell's text is "The" and the other is "Foxtrot", 'foxtrot's cell's image will be wider than 'the's. Also, I was under the impression that setting the owner as self is normal practice as per the docs?

Comment: Making yourself the owner of the table means that the instance variables you use to interact with the cell sub views only ever refer to the last cell created. No use if you are creating multiple cells.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because a table view cell is created at one size, and then it is resized when it is displayed after being added to the table.  If you log the bounds or frame of your cell, you will see that it is one size (smaller) when you load it from the nib, and another size (bigger) when you "refresh" the cell by scrolling it off of the screen and back on.

The simplest approach would be to make sure that the label and image both have the same auto-sizing rules, so that when the cell is resized, they both grow together.

Comment: I've just replied to @Wain - perhaps I wasn't clear in that I'm not focussed on the cell's height, but I'm trying to re-frame an image's width within the cell, according to the length of the UILabel's NSString that gets set when the cell is created. Hope that helps clarify my issue.

Comment: My answer is referring to the cell width, not the height.  The width changes after it is created to match the width of your table, in the orientation that it is in, which very likely resizes your label after you have set its width, depending on your autosizing mask.

Answer (score 1):

you can use UITableView delegate method,

```
     – (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

inside this you can set the height of row dynamically like..

// This is only for Example that you can set your cell height

```
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

          NSString *text;
     text = [_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(280, 2000);
     CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

     return size.height + 5; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to control the size of the subviews if you programmatically create them and add them to your tableview cell (i.e.,so that they are not set in storyboard, and thus are not subjected to explicit auto-contraints).

In my implementation, I created a customCell subclass.  In the .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *customLabel;
```

Then in the .m:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    METHOD;
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.customLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
        [self addSubview:self.customLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In your tableViewController's .m file, in the method tableView:cellForRowAtAtIndexPath:

```
theCell.customLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
theCell.customLabel.text = @"Whatever text you want";
```

This will give you instant and complete control over your custom label right when the tableview and cell loads.

In response to @inafziger, I tried programmatically removing the constraints on the label but it did not resolve this auto-resizing issue.

Update: making a temporary reference to the subview, then removing it from superview, and then adding it back to the subview, this worked just as well, with the slight exception that the in my case where I'm using a label, the height of the label was fit to the height of the text it contained (whereas programmatically creating the label in my example above, the label will have whatever height you assign it.)  The advantage being that you don't have to create any custom labels, or even touch the subclass tableviewCell.  Just use whatever you created in storyboard.  Here's tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UILabel *theLabel = theCell.theLabel;
[theCell.theLabel removeFromSuperview];
[theCell addSubview:theLabel];
theCell.theLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
```